# ¿Cómo consigo crear una nueva columna en un df buscando el valor en un segundo df si 2 de las variables tienen valores coincidentes?

Tags: r

Tengo 2 data frames en R Studio. En el primero esta información:

```
PARTNER PARTNER_ISO TRADE_TYPE PRODUCT_NC 
    3          NL          I   03036310   
    3          NL          I   03047110        
    3          NL          I   03047190        
    3          NL          I   03047411        
    3          NL          I   03047419        
    3          NL          I   03047490
```

Y en el segundo esta otra:

```
 TARIC      PARTNER              ESPECIE
03036310      3                  Albacore 
03047411      5                  Yellowfin
03047490      3, 7, 10           Bigeye
```

Quiero añadirle al primer dataframe el valor de ESPECIE del segundo dataframe si coinciden tanto el valor que encuentra en TARIC como el valor que encuentra en PARTNER. Hay que tener en cuenta que PARTNER en el segundo data frame es un listado de valores y debe de retornar el valor si coincide cualquiera de ellos.

He pensado que podía hacer una left join con merge pero la verdad es que no sé como decirle que considere 2 keys, y no lo encuentro por ningún sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Como bien comentas se debe usar un "Join" para realizar la fusión de tus dos data frames con dos condiciones.

Primero intente recrear tus dos data frames:

```
Partner <- rep(3, 4)
Partner_iso <- rep("Nl", 4) 
Trade_type <- rep("I", 4)
Product_id <- c(1111, 2222, 3333, 4444)

Taric <- c(1111, 2222, 3333, 4444)
Partner1 <- c(3,5,3, 5)
Especie <- c("Albacore", "Yellowfin", "Bigeye", "Alo")

A <- data.frame(Partner, Partner_iso, Trade_type, Product_id)
B <- data.frame(Taric, Partner1, Especie)
```

Así quedaron las tablas que cree:

```
> A
  Partner Partner_iso Trade_type Product_id
1       3          Nl          I       1111
2       3          Nl          I       2222
3       3          Nl          I       3333
4       3          Nl          I       4444

> B
  Taric Partner1   Especie
1  1111        3  Albacore
2  2222        5 Yellowfin
3  3333        3    Bigeye
4  4444        5       Alo
```

Una vez tengamos los dos data frames habrá que cambiar los nombres de las dos columnas que buscas ocupar como condicionales para que tengan el mismo nombre. En tu caso habría que cambiar los nombres del segundo data frame (la variable "TARIC" por "PRODUCT_NC" y las variables "PARTNER" y "ESPECIES" las dejamos igual). Esto lo logramos con la función colnames() como se muestra a continuación:

```
colnames(B) <- c("Product_id", "Partner", "Especie")
```

Por ultimo, toca realizar un "inner_join", un "right_join", un "left_join" o un "outer_join" según lo que necesites.
Comparto enlace sobre que significa cada uno de los JOIN https://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/join-in-r-merge-in-r/

En el primer caso ocupó un INNER_JOIN que permite conservar UNICAMENTE los datos que hagan match con las dos condiciones:

```
A %>% inner_join(B, by=c("Product_id","Partner"))
```

El output es:

```
  Partner Partner_iso Trade_type Product_id  Especie
1       3          Nl          I       1111 Albacore
2       3          Nl          I       3333   Bigeye
```

En el segundo caso ocupo un OUTER_JOIN que permite conservar TODOS los datos, agregando NA a los datos que no respondan a ninguna condición.

```
merge(x=A,y=B,by=c("Product_id","Partner"),all=TRUE)
```

El output es el siguiente:

```
  Product_id Partner Partner_iso Trade_type   Especie
1       1111       3          Nl          I  Albacore
2       2222       3          Nl          I      <NA>
3       2222       5        <NA>       <NA> Yellowfin
4       3333       3          Nl          I    Bigeye
5       4444       3          Nl          I      <NA>
6       4444       5        <NA>       <NA>       Alo
```

Espero te haya sido de utilidad. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si has trabajado con `tidyverse` verás que es bastante sencillo, el secreto es "expandir" los valores que hoy tienes en una cadena separada por comas en filas reales, luego simplemente es aplicar el `join` correspondiente:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2 %>% 
            separate_rows(PARTNER, convert = TRUE),
            by = c("PRODUCT_NC" = "TARIC", "PARTNER")
  )

  PARTNER PARTNER_ISO TRADE_TYPE PRODUCT_NC  ESPECIE
1       3          NL          I    3036310 Albacore
2       3          NL          I    3047110     <NA>
3       3          NL          I    3047190     <NA>
4       3          NL          I    3047411     <NA>
5       3          NL          I    3047419     <NA>
6       3          NL          I    3047490   Bigeye
```

Comentarios:

- `separate_rows(PARTNER, convert = TRUE)` expande esta columna en filas, tomando cada valor separando por coma. `convert = TRUE` para convertir la cadena en un numérico consistente con el otro `data.frame`